# What is the proper way to reference another resource in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

So I'm trying to wrap my head around JSON-LD, and all the examples I see mainly consist of embedding "linked data".  But I want to provide references to linked data (mainly because embedding it all could result in 10MB payloads).  So I'm wondering if I'm doing this right.

Here's what I have:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Customers.jsonld",
  "@id": "/customers/1",
  "@type": "Customer",
  "sessions": {
    "@id": "/customers/1/sessions",
    "@type": "Session"
  },
  "dealer": "/dealers/2",
  "givenName": "Abe",
  "familyName": "Abrahms",
  /* ... snip ... */
}
```

The reference to linked data that I'm talking about here is represented by the `sessions` property.  Assuming that is correct, then what would I need to change in my `Customer` context?

```
"@context": {
    "hydra": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#",
    "doc": "https://api.waterlinkconnect.com/doc#",
    "Customer": "doc:Customer",
    "givenName": "doc:Customer/givenName",
    "familyName": "doc:Customer/familyName",
    "email":"doc:Customer/email",
    "address":"doc:Customer/address",
    "notes":"doc:Customer/notes",
    "phone1":"doc:Customer/phone1",
    "phone2":"doc:Customer/phone2"
    "sessions": "???????"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to provide an IRI as value, e.g.:

```json
"propertyFoo": { "@id": "https://example.com/some-iri" }
```

(`@id` is used here so that the IRI does not get interpreted as string value.)

So your example with `sessions` is fine, but you don’t *have* to provide a `@type` if you don’t want/need it.

#### With [type coercion](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#type-coercion)

If this property always gets an IRI as value, you could define this in your `@context`:

```json
"propertyFoo": 
{ 
  "@id": "https://your-vocabulary.example.com/propertyFoo",
  "@type": "@id"
}
```

Then you can omit the `@id` when providing a value:

```json
"propertyFoo": "https://example.com/some-iri"
```

(If using type coercion like this, you can’t provide additional properties for that node.)

Comment: `"property": { "https://example.com/some-iri" }` wouldn't that be invalid JSON, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: Ah, right (I copy-pasted the previous example and didn’t remove enough^^), thanks! I edited my answer and removed the `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thank you, one last question, when I test my modified context using the `"property": { "@type": "@id" }` on the json-ld playground, I get the error: `Invalid JSON-LD syntax; @context terms must define an @id.`  Apparently it wants me to add an `@id` for the property, I'm assuming that `@id` would be the context of the Session right?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: It has to be the IRI for that property (as it’s the job of the `@context` to map terms to IRIs). So if you were using [`image`](http://schema.org/image) as defined by Schema.org, it would be `"@id": "http://schema.org/image"`. If you use a property not defined by another vocabulary (i.e., your own/custom property), you’d ideally use an IRI under your own domain (making it globally unique).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again for the additional information!